# Typings tool install local

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

How can i install typings 'locally' and not 'globally'.

I do not want to install jquery typings globally since its version can change for example in the future and hence its typings might change.

i understand there is the

> typings install dt~angular-formly --global

but i want to install it locally, I am unable to find any reference on that.

Also it says here that - https://github.com/typings/typings

> ## Use `typings/index.d.ts` (in `tsconfig.json` or as a `///` reference). cat typings/index.d.ts

That tells me absolutely nothing.How can i use index.d.ts in tsconfig.json.

what is ?

> 'cat typings/index.d.ts'

If i understand correctly index.d.ts bundles all the installed typings so i can get intellisense.Fair enough.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple questions :-(

1. Have you tried:
   typings install dt~angular-formly
2. No idea what you mean.
3. cat typings/index.d.ts
   This is the command in linux and os/x to list the contents of index.d.ts